# Circle ProgressBar Android change Thickness etc

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-progressbar

I am using the "normal" circle ProgressBar of Android which looks like this:

[image: rogr]

So, what I would like to do is to change the color, thickness and the corners (with cornerradius) of this ProgressBar.

I've found some examples for doing this stuff, but however it only was for horizontal ProgressBars, but I would like to keep this original ProgressBar.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 10):

A progress bar is essentially a `rotate` animation drawable. Here's something we use that is thinner with a different color gradient. You can see the use of `thickness` for width and `start` and `end` color.

Tweak to your liking:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="720" >

  <shape
      android:shape="ring"
      android:thickness="@dimen/progress_circle_thickness"
      android:useLevel="false" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="@color/progress_circle"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
  </shape>
</rotate>
```

and use in your layout something like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_circle"/>
```

Comment: Your answer changes the behavior of the progress bar. The author was particular about  keeping the original ProgressBar

Comment: I'm not here to design the assets for the OP's progress bar, unless they want to hire me. The answer above gives an example of how to create a custom progress bar. The rest is an excercise for the reader.